# Atom search and replace with regex to add a new class

Tags: javascript, html, regex, atom-editor

I have been searching about regular expression, but I am not using it on a javascript file or any program.

I just want to search and replace, using Atom.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="content">
        <span class="user">User One</span><span class=
        "meta">Sunday, 31 July 2013 at 22:19 UTC+01</span>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Hello</p>
```

All I want is search in the whole doc in order to add a class on the last paragraph. The only thing that changes is the date and time, the rest is the same.

For instance:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="content">
        <span class="user">User One</span><span class=
        "meta">WHATEVER</span>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="new-class">Hello</p>
```

Any ideas?

***EDIT***

I was thinking in something like:

**SEARCH**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="content">
        <span class="user">User One</span><span class=
        "meta">***REGULAR EXPRESSION****</span>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
```

**REPLACE**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="content">
        <span class="user">User One</span><span class=
        "meta">***REGULAR EXPRESSION****</span>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="new-class">
```

Comment: Do you want to replace ALL instances of `p`?

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: Maybe find `([\S\s]*)<p>` replace `\1<p class="new-class">`

Comment: Not because there are "two users" and the class must be added to the paragraph of the User One, for that reason I would like to search everythin.

Comment: JavaScript might be a little lightweight for what you need the regex to do. I'll post something you could try.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

Find:

```
/(?si)(<span(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sclass\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*user\s*\2))\s+(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+>\s*User\s*One\s*<\/span\s*>.*?)<p\s*>/
```

Replace:

```
$1<p class="new-class">
```

Expanded

```
 (?si)
 (                             # (1 start)
      <span
      (?=
           (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
           \s class \s* = \s* 
           (?:
                ( ['"] )                      # (2)
                \s* user \s* \2 
           )
      )
      \s+ 
      (?: " .*? " | ' .*? ' | [^>]*? )+
      >
      \s* User \s* One \s* 
      </span \s* >
      .*? 
 )                             # (1 end)
 <p \s* >
```